# Is using the "hidden" html attribute to hide table cells because of rowspan and colspan semantically incorrect?

Tags: html, html-table, hidden, semantic-markup

Is using the "hidden" attribute semantically correct when hiding the table cell because of the rowspan and colspan attribute of another table cell?

I could find only examples which entirely remove the table cells to make space for the cell(s) spanning multiple rows and cols (having the `rowspan` and `colspan` attributes).

Example:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" rowspan="2">#1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>#7</td>
    <td>#8</td>
    <td>#9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But is it semantically valid to do something like this?

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" rowspan="2">#1</td>
    <td hidden></td>
    <td hidden></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td hidden></td>
    <td hidden></td>
    <td hidden></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>#7</td>
    <td>#8</td>
    <td>#9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Just to give a little context: I'm working on a rich text editor having a constraint that empty span elements are being added to empty block elements. Having a span element inside an empty table row would be considered invalid HTML (`tr` can only have `td` and `th` as child elements).

I've been researching a bit but couldn't find a definitive answer to my question.

Comment: Either the cell exists or it does not. If you use row/col-span then you merge 2 cells and the other cells should not exist.

Answer (score 1):

It's incorrect, and you don't need to write these cells in the HTML at all. The correct HTML for your example is as follows.

Having an identical rowspan value over all cells of a row (like in your first cell which spans all columns) does not make sense – this isn't a grid system but just a table which will contain whatever content you put into it.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 300px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  vertical-align: top;
}

tr:first-child > td {
  height: 2.8em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">#1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>#7</td>
    <td>#8</td>
    <td>#9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```